# Prime Factorization in Java

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I'm working on a prime factorization program in Java one that displays all prime factors of a number even if they are repeated. And I have this:

```
public static void factors(int a)
{
    int c=1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= a;i++)
    {
        if(a%i == 0)
        {
            for(int k = 2; k < i; k++)
            {
                if(i%k == 0)
                {
                    c = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    c = 0;
                }
            }
            if(c == 0 || i == 2)
            {
                System.out.print(i+ ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to account for repeated factors (as in 2, 2, 2 for 8). How could I do that without completely restructuring?

Comment: Keep dividing out factors until you can't divide no more. It doesn't matter whether the factors are repeated or not.

Comment: Are you sure your problem requirement is being correctly understood. Usually, you either list all factors (so 12 would be 1,2,3,4,6,12) or you factorize (so 12 would be 2,2,3). What you seem to be trying to do is something oddly in-between.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag the question as such. Also, what do you mean by *"without completely restructuring"*?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start over, and build an algorithm from this simple description:

- Prepare a `List<Integer>` of prime numbers that are less than or equal to 2^16
- Run through this list from low to high, trying each prime in turn as a candidate divisor
- Every time you run into a working divisor, continually divide it out until you can no longer divide the number by it; then continue to the next prime
- Once you reach the end of the list of primes, your remaining number should be printed as well, unless it is equal to `1`.

Finding a list of primes is a fun problem in itself. Dijkstra wrote a fascinating chapter on it back in 1972. [This article](http://vanemden.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/another-scoop-by-dijkstra/) has a C++ implementation and a very nice discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can have another collection that maintains the factors and their count and can finally account for repeated factors. A map with counts would be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

(1) `if(c == 0 || i == 2)`  is wrong, it will print `2` for `a == 5` as well.

(2)  In order to do what you are asking without changing the code (*) - you should count how many times each prime factor is diviseable by the number. It can be done by simply adding a new loop before your print statement [pseudo code]:

```
boolean b = true;
int k = 1;
while (b) { 
  if (a % (int) Math.pow(i, k+1) == 0) k++;
  else b = false;
}
```

at the end of this loop, k denotes how many times `i` is a prime factor of `a`.

(*) Note: Though this approach should work, I'd still go with @KerrekSB suggestion to a redesign.